# Local Notification getting replaced

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I'm showing a Local Notification every time when my app receives a significant location update while being in the background. For some reason the notification is overwriting the previous notification every time. I would like to keep all local notifications shown on the screen until the user opens the app. How can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance %.1f km",self.calculatedDistance];
[notification setAlertBody:message];
[notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  defaultTimeZone]];

NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:message forKey:@"msg"];
notification.userInfo = infoDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
```

with:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```